A box-like structure to store/for storing rain shutters (in)
(1) Here in Japan, we use a box-like structure to store rain shutters in.
(2) Here in Japan, we use a box-like structure for storing rain shutters in.
In each of my sentences above, is in necessary, wrong, or optional?

It is the verb use that is creating the disturbance.

I'm shopping for a box to store my shutters in.

That is a perfectly idiomatic sentence.
Even though the following  is  marginal,  you'd hear it quite often in conversational American English:

I use a box to store my shutters in.

The speakers are probably analogizing from other verbs where there is no problemmatic usage:

I need a box to store my shutters in.


Thank you very much, TimR. There seem to be many differences between AE and BE regarding the choice and omission of prepositions.

I have seen "learn proper grammar at home" booklets from the early part of the 20th century, written for the person who works in an office but did not go to college, which taught that  stranding prepositions was the telltale sign of an uneducated person.  The practice has been stigmatized.  But it comes from the Germanic and Scandinavian  side of the English language.

Optional, but best avoided, especially in (2)
Traditional grammarians would have "a box in which to store rain shutters."
The prepostion "in" serves no purpose in your examples and should be omitted.

According to what I learned in school, both "a box to store rain shutters in" and "a box  in which to store rain shutters" are correct, so I thought (1) might be natural. It is hard for this self-learner to learn idiomatic English (especially idiomatic spoken English). Your answer is immensely helpful. Thank you very much, JamesK.

Yes, but the verb "store" doesn't need a prepositional phrase at all,

I would find the versions ending with in perfectly natural, even though  the in is technically unnecessary. Compare Winnie-the-Pooh's a useful pot to put things in

Thank you very much, Kate Bunting. I have seen a few times in a learners' dictionary a phrase similar to "a useful pot to put things in".

Exactly, because you can "store something"  but you cannot "put something".  With "put" the prepositional phrase is required.  You have to "put something in something".  You can say "Store the shutters" but you have to say "put the shutters in a box"  You can't say "put the shutters".

That last comment is not necessarily so: Where did you put the shutters? In the box? No, I didn

I'm not sure you get my point,  @Lambie  In a question, the prepositional phrase (or what ever) might be removed, replaced with a question word, and fronted.  There's no prepositional phrase, for sure, but there is the word "where".  You still can't (usually, and in unexceptional situations) make a statement "I put the shutters".

We should remove in:

We use a box-like structure to store rain shutters.

We should be careful, though, to regularly check the box.  We wouldn't want the termites to say
We use a box-like structure to build our nest in.
The second similarly should have in removed:

We use a box-like structure for storing rain shutters.

Edit
Constructions ending with in like the OP’s example

We use a box-like structure to store rain shutters in.

are quite common too in the US although the in is unnecessary.  Please see examples in the comments.

As a self-learner who is trying to learn idiomatic English, your answer is immensely helpful. Thank you very much, Seowjooheng Singapore.

"to build our nest in" is something you'd hear very often in the US.  "I need a box to put my papers in."  "I need a box to store my papers in."  How do you your store your spice jars? --  I have a box to keep my spice jars in."  Even with "use".  I use a box to keep my spice jars in.   It's verbose, but common in colloquial speech.  Edited: "I keep my spice jars in a box".

Thanks, @TimR, for sharing.  I've edited my answer.
